# таблица bootstrap

Tags: html, django, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap4

используя фреймворк бутстрап которий получает массив пробую создать таблицу

| id | general_name | sub_name | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | test | 1 |
| 2 | tom | test2 | 1 |
| 3 | tom | test3 | 1 |
| 2 | sara | test2 | 1 |
| 3 | sara | test3 | 1 |
| -- | ------------ | -------- | ----- |

Как их используя бутстрап можно сгрупировать? чтоб получилось чтото типа

```
|id|general_name|sub_name|count|
|--|------------|--------|-----|
|1 |tom         |test    |1    |
|2 |            |test2   |1    |
|3 |            |test3   |1    |
|2 |sara        |test2   |1    |
|3 |            |test3   |1    |
```

желательно без линий там гре пусто а том и сара по центру

ну мне нужно чтоб в таком виде все сделать вот код

```
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>general_name</th>
                <th>sub_name</th>
                <th>count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in access_rules %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.subname  }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.count}}</td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Группировка и бутстрап - это разное. Покажите код, с которым возникли сложности

Comment: ну мне нужно чтоб в таком виде все сделать вот код

<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>general_name</th>
                <th>sub_name</th>
                <th>count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in access_rules %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.subname  }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.count}}</td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

Comment: Это какой то шаблон, который заполняется хз где. Это на сервере рисуется или на клиенте? На каком языке это делается -> `{% for row in access_rules %}`?

Comment: jinja 2 поняла нарисую на беке и передам на фронт код html